# 曖昧検索のLIKE文にヒットしない

Tags: go, sql, postgresql, gorm

Go言語のgormというORMでpostgreSQLのLIKE文を使用しましたが、なぜかデータがとれません。

モデルは以下のものを想定します。

```
type Model struct{
    ID int
    Name string     
    Phonetic string //Nameのひらがな
}
```

ここでPhoneticがあ行で始まるものを取得したいので、下記のSQLを発行します。
`db.Where("phonetic LIKE ?", "[あ-お|ぁ-ぉ]%").Find(&models)`

しかし、データ内にPhoneticがあ行で始まるもの(例えば｢おーろら｣など)があるのですが、取得できません。どのようなSQLを発行すれば取れるのでしょうか。

Comment: LIKE では `[]`(bracket) が使えません。なので、Postgresql なら `tilda` を使って `"phonetic ~ ?", "^[あ-おぁ-ぉ]"`、sqlite3 なら `glob` を使って `"phonetic GLOB ?", "[あ-おぁ-ぉ]*"` となるかと。MySQL であれば、おそらく `REGEXP` が使えるかもしれません(未確認)。

Comment: チルダを使う方法でできました。あらがとうございます。すみません1つ疑問なのですが[あ-お|ぁ-ぉ]でなくてもいいのでしょうか。あと例えば｢た-と｣と｢っ｣をマッチさせたい時はどうすればいいのでしょうか。

Comment: はい、`|` を`[]`の中に入れてしまうと、`|` 文字そのものにマッチするという意味になってしまいますので、今回は必要ないのではないかと。次のご質問の答えはおそらく、`[たちっつてと]` になります(未確認なので後から修正するかもしれません)。

Comment: UTF-8 テーブルを確認してみたのですが、文字コードの並びを見ますと、`[た-と] == [ただちぢっつづてでと]` となっています。濁点も含めるのであれば、`[た-と]` だけで `っ` も入ります。含めたくない場合は、前述の様に一文字づつ指定することになります。

Comment: わざわざありがとうございます。濁点もマッチして欲しいので`[た-と]`を使いたいと思います。

Comment: だとするともしかして`[ぁ-ぉ]`も`[あ-お]`に入ってるのでしょうか

Comment: あ、そうですね、入っていますね(苦笑)。ただし、`[ぁ-お]` となります。

Comment: これは便利ですね。`[ぁ-お]`の形を使用したいと思います。いろいろありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE` 演算子が行うのはとても単純なパターンマッチであり、正規表現によるマッチではありません: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html

PostgreSQL では `~` 演算子で正規表現を使ったマッチができるので、これを利用することは一応できます。`phonetic ~ '^[あ-お|ぁ-ぉ]'` といった感じです。

ただし正規表現を使ったマッチはインデックスを利用しづらいなどのデメリットがあり、レコード数が多くなるとクエリ実行に時間がかかりがちです。実行時間で困る場合、1 文字目しか利用しないのであればそのためのカラムを作るとか、色々な検索パターンがありえるのであれば全文検索エンジンの利用を検討するとかが考えられます。